# Knockout unwrap complex objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've got the following code snippet

```
function Person() {
    var id;
    var name;
    var loginName;
    var email;
}

function Substitude() {
    this.substitude = ko.observable(new Person());
    this.subBegin = ko.observable(Date());
    this.subEnd = ko.observable(Date());
}

function SampleSubstitude() {
    var testing = ko.observable(new Substitude());
    var tester = getPerson(88,"Alpha Tester","a.tester","a.tester@example.com");

    testing.substitude = tester;

    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(testing);
}

function getPerson(id, name, login, email) {
    var person = ko.observable(new Person());
    person.id = id;
    person.name = name;
    person.loginName = login;
    person.email = email;

    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(person);

}
```

This is my View Model:

```
function AbsenceRequestModel() {
    this.delegations = ko.observableArray();
    this.addsubstitudeclick = function () {
        var raw = SampleSubstitude();
        var obj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(new raw());
        this.delegations.push(obj);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately all values pushed to my array are empty. Can anybody give me a hint, what's wrong about here?

Comment: It's Substitute, not Substitude. That's more of a grammar thing, but I had to say it.

Comment: @arkanciscan: It's more of a *spelling* thing. Not related to grammar. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
function Person(id, name, login, email) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.loginName = ko.observable(login);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
}
```

variables were set private before, didn't took notice about it.
thanks for help all.

Answer (score 8):

If all of the values are observable, then you don't need a proxy method between your `Person` constructor and your object:

```
function Person(id, name, login, email) {
    var id = ko.observable(id);
    var name = ko.observable(name);
    var loginName = ko.observable(login);
    var email = ko.observable(email);
}

var person = new Person(1, "Name", "LoginName", 'aaaa@abc.cde');
>> ko.toJS(person) 
{
    id : 1,
    name : "Name",
    loginName : "LoginName",
    email : "aaaa@abc.cde"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set values to the observable op the person

```
person().id = id;
person().name = name;
person().loginName = login;
person().email = email;
```